# Testing ant design form with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, jestjs, enzyme

i am trying to test a form in jest/enzyme eith typescript, however i get stuck. Here is the example:

```
class TestForm extends React.Component<FormComponentProps> {
    render() {
        console.log("TESTFORMPROPS: ", this.props)
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <Form>
                <Form.Item label="name">
                    {getFieldDecorator('name', {
                        rules: [
                            {
                                type: 'string',
                                required: true,
                            },
                        ],
                        initialValue: 'mary',
                    })(<input />)}
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
const WrappedForm = Form.create()(TestForm);
```

now when i look at the log ("TESTFORMPROPS: ") i clearly see a form however if i do the following test:

```
describe(`Testing the Login component`, () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<WrappedForm/>);
    console.log("TESTINGPROPS: ", wrapper.props())
    });
```

I get at the log ("TESTINGPROPS: "):

`{}`

anyone an idea on how to test ant design forms in react with enzyme and jest using typescript?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Maybe you can tell us the exact behaviour?

Comment: eventually, i want to try to test the validation of a more complex form with credentials. To do that i need to have the form values and the submit function in the class. 

In this example i am trying to get the form by calling props in the wrapper. However it is empty which is quite confusing since the form should be a prop of my class.